# two database hierarchy methods

Tags: database, hierarchy

I'm surprised but searching for this is difficult because I don't know the term, and "database hierarchy" means something else.

I am very familiar with a self-referencing hierarchy table where each row has an ID field and also a Parent_ID field, so that any row can have a parent, creating effectively a "tree"

However I know there is another method that uses LEFT and RIGHT fields and relative position left and right overall.  Have never used it but it's in a codebase which I'm working on.  Can anyone give me some links to this type of heirarchy structure?  Thanks

Comment: Search for "nested set model"

Answer (score 0):

oops should have thought of this: search for:

```
left right hierarchy
```

that affords a plethora of images, in addition to the "nested set model" mentioned above.  Thanks!